# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException creating Database dynamically in HSQLDB

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I have HSQLDB running as a server. I have the remote_open property set to true so that I can create new databases dynamically.

When I am trying to create a new database I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -1. I look at the folder structure and it seems that the DB files are all there; it is just not being added to the databases on the server.

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb;filepath=file:C:/files/mydatabase", "SA", "");
```

Exception thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post relevant code and any error messages you get, along with line numbers

Comment: Sorry. New to asking questions. I have added the exception I get from the line of code above.

Comment: @Reebot Hello Mr.Reebot,how have you created database on HSQLDB server dynamically ? Any help most appreciable.